# Dymanic URL htaccess 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have multi-url redirects and I need to make 301 redirects from?

```
RewriteRule ^car/([^/]+)/model-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$ new_car.php?     model=$1&name=$2&year=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I need to make a redirect 301 from old url to working new

Comment: Do you mean 

`new_car.php?     model=$1&name=$2&year=$3` **to** `^car/([^/]+)/model-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$` ?

Comment: yes, I guess it will be external redirection. When user try to `code new_car.php? model=$1&name=$2&year=$3 code` page will be redirected to `code^car/([^/]+)/model-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the following :

```
#1 301 redirect from  the old location to the new
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /new_car\.php\?model=([^&]+)&name=([^&]+)&year=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /car/%1/model-%2-%3/? [L,R=301]
#2 internally redirect from  the new location to the old
RewriteRule ^car/([^/]+)/model-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ new_car.php?     model=$1&name=$2&year=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have last question, how it will be possible to add partiation like &page=2 to the end of this urls?

Comment: &page=2 is part of query string ,  QSA flag will automatically append this to the old url if the requested url is **/cars/foo/bar/?page=2**

Comment: Does it possible to make SEO friendly by redirect?